# Is it necessary to use a keyhole contour when the integral has a square root?

Tags: complex-analysis

Many books suggest using the keyhole contour when dealing with non-integer powers. Is this necessary? For example, is there a better way to solve $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+x+1}dx?$$

Comment: Because $\sqrt{z}$ is a multivalued function, not analytic in a nbd of zero.

Comment: It's not necessary, a semicircle contour also suffices here